# Camel-jms A destination named was not found on WebLogic

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, weblogic

I'm trying to use JMS queues in weblogic 12.1.3 with camel-jms.
When I try to save something in the queue I get the error:

```
Caused By: weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: [JMSExceptions:045102]A destination named "jms/TestJMSQueue" was not found on WebLogic Server instance "AdminServer".
```

To configure the jms queue on the server I followed this tutorial:
https://blogs.oracle.com/soaproactive/entry/how_to_create_a_simple

My camel config:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="weblogic" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myConnectionFactory" jndi-name=" jms/TestConnectionFactory "/>
</beans>
```

To write in a queue:

```
.to("weblogic:.jms/TestJMSQueue")
```

What is the syntax for writing in the queue?

I have tried the name (TestJMSQueue) and the jndi (jms / TestJMSQueue), but I get the same error.

How do I save a bean in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

The queue name is "TestJMSQueue". "jms/TestJMSQueue" is the name of the queue object in JNDI. Try using the plain queue name:

```
.to("weblogic:TestJMSQueue")
```

Comment: I solve my problem using the module name too. This way TestJMSModule!TestJMSQueue. Thanks.

Comment: Is it `to("weblogic:.jms/TestJMSModule!TestJMSQueue")`?

Comment: `to("jms:queue:TestJMSModule!TestJMSQueue")` this works for me. Thanks